# Django On Delete IntegrityError

Tags: django

I get an integrity Error on deleting a Company. See this code below

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, db_index=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, db_index=True)
    fmp_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    stock_exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exchange = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

class CalculationYearlyGrowth(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    current = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
    historical_data = models.ForeignKey(CalculatedHistoricalFundamental, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is the error I got

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: update or delete on table
> "company_company" violates foreign key constraint
> "company_calculationy_company_id_c31e6552_fk_company_c" on table
> "company_calculationyearlygrowth" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(308248) is still
> referenced from table "company_calculationyearlygrowth".

So every time I want to delete a company and wherever it has foreign relations, I first have to delete CalculationYearlyGrowth of that company manually and I can't delete the Company. I have seen some other questions related to this but None have worked for me and the error itself is confusing since I have a Cascade delete so I don't expect the error to come. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class CalculationYearlyGrowth(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

did you add `on_delete=models.CASCADE` recently? you may have to:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

for that to come into effect. The `models.CASCADE` should in theory mean that when the company is deleted it auto deletes the `CalculationYearlyGrowth`

Comment: I have not added models.CASCADE recently, it was there from the start, and thats why the error is even more confusing.

Comment: name of the table is not what i would expect `company_calculationyearlygrowth` in your error. i would expect it to just be calculationyearlygrowth. is there another model or table that is just free floating in your database that shouldn't be there any more?